# how to fetch data with same id in a row but different value in another column and display into table in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have following data in my SQL table:

```
id      code     day     time    year
 1     PRC-001    0       t-1     2017
 2     PRC-001    1       t-2     2017
 3     PRC-002    0       t-3     2017
 4     PRC-002    1       t-4     2017
 5     PRC-003    0       t-5     2017
 6     PRC-003    1       t-6     2017
```

Output should be like this:

```
day0     day1     code      
 t-1      t-2    PRC-001
 t-3      t-4    PRC-002    
 t-5      t-6    PRC-003
```

How can I do this? I was trying something like the following code. But I didn't get any desire output. Here is my code:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM routine AS tab1,"; 
$query1.= " GROUP BY code";

$rs = mysql_query($query1);
$numOfRows=mysql_num_rows($rs);
$printed = array();
$resultset = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $resultset[] = $row;
    #print_r($row);
}

$q = "<table id='ash'>";
$q.= "<tr id='grey'>";
$q.= "<th rowspan='2'>day0</th>";
$q.= "<th rowspan='2'>day1(s)</th>";
$q.= "<th rowspan='2'>code</th></tr>";
$q.= "</tr>";


foreach ($resultset as $row){ 
    $q.= "<tr>";
    $q.= "<tr><td id='clist'>".$row["time"]."</td>";
    $q.= "<td id='clist'>".$row["time"]."</td>";
    $q.= "<td id='clist'>".$row["code"]."</td></tr>";
} 
$q .= "</table>";
echo $q;
```

Comment: Will the `day` column have only values `0` and `1`?

Comment: yeah
I think it can be done by if else condition. But can't find the exact way.

Comment: Just an FYI but you should try and avoid using `mysql_` functions. There are the `mysqli_` functions (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) which share a very similar api though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: That query will obviously trigger an error. And PHP's mysql_ API was effectively deprecated years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as mentioned in the comments you should look at using something other than the `mysql_` functions.

Second, with you're query you need to remove the `GROUP BY`.

Then you could do something like:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM routine");

$results = [];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {

    $code = $row['code'];

    if (!isset($results[$code])) {
        $results[$code] = [
            'day0' => '-',
            'day1' => '-',
        ];
    }

    $results[$code]['day' . $row['day']] = $row['time'];

}

?>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr id="grey">
        <th rowspan="2">Day0</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Day1(s)</th>
        <th rowspan="2">code</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($results as $code => $result) : ?>
        <!--You shouldn't have multiple elements using the same ids-->
        <tr>
            <td id='clist'><?php echo $result['day0'] ?></td>
            <td id='clist'><?php echo $result['day1'] ?></td>
            <td id='clist'><?php echo $code ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. it works :)
I have another query. If I want to set the value of fetched data, how can I write a function for that? For example:
t-1=> "09:30 A.M. - 10:30 A.M."
t-2=> "10:40 A.M. - 11:40 A.M."
t-3=> "11:50 A.M. - 12:50 P.M."

Comment: @TanzilaIslam As it's a different question it goes outside the scope of this one. Please could you open a new question and I'll happily have a look :)

Comment: I have asked a new question here. Can you answer?

Answer (score 0):

according to your desired table, the columns in a row  are not in a row in database table! so you can not build table with just a foreach through query results.

for example, `t-1, t-2 and PRC-001`  are not in a row in database. if day0 is `t-1` then day1 would be empty and vice versa.

**solution:**

you have to put `empty or zero` for one of `days` in final table to make sense ,  and you don't need `groupby`:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM routine AS tab1"; 


$rs = mysql_query($query1);
$numOfRows=mysql_num_rows($rs);
$printed = array();
$resultset = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $resultset[] = $row;
    #print_r($row);
}

$q = "<table id='ash'>";
$q.= "<tr id='grey'>";
$q.= "<th rowspan='2'>day0</th>";
$q.= "<th rowspan='2'>day1(s)</th>";
$q.= "<th rowspan='2'>code</th></tr>";
$q.= "</tr>";


foreach ($resultset as $row){ 

    if($row['day'] == 0){
        $q.= "<tr>";
        $q.= "<tr><td id='clist'>".$row["time"]."</td>";
        $q.= "<td id='clist'>"EMPTY!"</td>";
        $q.= "<td id='clist'>".$row["code"]."</td></tr>";
    } else {
        $q.= "<tr>";
        $q.= "<tr><td id='clist'>"EMPTY!"</td>";
        $q.= "<td id='clist'>".$row["time"]."</td>";
        $q.= "<td id='clist'>".$row["code"]."</td></tr>";   
    }

} 
$q .= "</table>";
echo $q;
```